# Trying to modify array in function in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_array(int *arr) {
  FILE *fp;
  int var;
  int i = 0;
  fp = fopen("array.txt", "r");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &var);
    arr[i] = var;
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
  int array[10];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
  }
  read_array(array[10]);
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is my code.
I'm trying to modify the array inside the function, based on a text file i have, that already has 10 numbers(0-9). What do I do wrong here?
Thanks for input guys & wish you the best! You the coolest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling us what the error or problem is, but I can make an educated guess:

```
read_array(array[10]);
```

should be just

```
read_array(array);
```

Beyond that, though, `read_array()` should preferably also take a maximum size argument, because otherwise it has no way of knowing the size of the `array`. For your program, it does happen to always be 10. Something like this:

```
/**
Read up to `n` integers from `array.txt` into the array `arr`,
returning the count that was successfully read.
*/
int read_array(int *arr, int n) {
  FILE *fp;
  int var;
  int i;
  fp = fopen("array.txt", "r");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &var) < 1) {  // < 1 means EOF or scan failed
      break;
    }
    arr[i] = var;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Its working now. What a silly mistake.
Could you please give me an example on your explanation of the maximum size argument? I don't quite understand it fully

Answer (score 2):

The principle you must understand, that underlies the correct answer from @AKX, is *Array / Pointer Conversion*. It is covered in the C-Standard as follows:

> 6.3.2.1  Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> (p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the
> `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string
> literal* used to initialize an array, an expression that has type
> *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is
> not an lvalue.

[C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

(**note:** the C17 standard removes `_Alignof` as an exception to the rule)

What this means is that any time you access an array, the array is converted to a pointer to its first element. So where you have:

```
int array[10];
```

and your function declaration is:

```
void read_array(int *arr)
```

(a function taking a *pointer-to* `int` as its parameter)

Then to provide the *pointer-to* `int` you need only provide the array name, `array`, as the argument -- which due to [6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) is converted to a pointer to the first element in the array. That is how you pass the array to your function.